# Поиск ближайшего большего значения в массиве

Tags: python

есть возрастающий массив [1,2, 5, 22, 33, 44, 312] и мне нужно получить ближайшее большее значение для числа, например для 10 это будет 22, для 3 это 5 и тд

Comment: минимум от фильтр на больше

Answer (score 2):

Если совсем просто то так:

```
number = 10
array = [3,5,7,22,55,123]
i = 0
while i <= len(array):
    if number <= array[i]:
        requiredNumber = array[i]
    i +=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def binary_search(data, elem):
    elem+=1
    low = 0
    high = len(data) - 1

    while low <= high:
      
        middle = (low + high)//2
       
        if data[middle] == elem:
            return middle
        elif data[middle] > elem:
            high = middle - 1
        else:
            low = middle + 1

    return middle
```

Код основан на бинаронм поиске, он находит первый элемент >=x, точнее его индекс

Comment: Вроде middle вне цикла не будет доступен?

Answer (score 0):

Для неотсортированного массива. Для отсортированного лучше использовать бинпоиск.

Python 3.4+: [tio.run](https://tio.run/##XU1LCsIwFNznFLNM4C2apm6EegQvIC4emGCgvpSQSj19fHQlbubHDLN@2rNI6P0RE5JlwpsXdzZAjW2rglcWa3ekUrEjCxg5qbocPYLOeFvafC0SnTGMGTdPGAknRaUQCNOk7Me7WWuWZo@b4Nyv9cO/HzTp/Qs)

```
def f(a, val):
  return min((x for x in a if x > val), default=None)

a = [1, 2, 5, 22, 33, 44, 312]
print(f(a, 3))
print(f(a, 10))
print(f(a, 1000))
```

Более ранние версии: [tio.run](https://tio.run/##XY1BCsMgFET3nmKWCi5iTDeF9gi9gLgQokRov0FsSE9vf7sK2czMGwZm/bSlkO19jglJBo0tPNVVADW2dyW8Mkm3I5WKHZkQkBOn@2/nwa17FIpeCRFwgzMao8aFlc1ajWliN6MXa83U5P/CKnVEM5x54Kb3Lw)

```
def f(a, val):
  return min([x for x in a if x > val] or [None])

a = [1, 2, 5, 22, 33, 44, 312]
print(f(a, 3))
print(f(a, 10))
print(f(a, 1000))
```

Вывод в обоих случаях:

```
5
22
None
```

Comment: если вместо 'min' взять 'next' то получится немного быстрее 'next((x for x in a if x > val), None)'

Comment: @SergFSM, но работать будет только на отсортированном массиве, а там лучше вообще не этот способ использовать.

Comment: полностью согласен